# How to check a number is out of the range of Integer type?

Tags: java

How to check a number is out of the range of Integer?

If the number is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, return `Integer.MAX_VAlUE`

If the number is less than `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, return `Integer.MIN_VAlUE`

EX:
2000000000000 -> `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

This is my solution, but it seems very inefficient.

```
if(str.length() >= 10) {
    if(str.charAt(0) != '-') {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    } else if(str.length() >= 11 && str.charAt(0) == '-') {
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can parse it as a ``Long`` or ``BigInteger`` and then compare it to ``Integer.MAX_VALUE``.

Comment: why you compare size of string with Integer.MAX_VAL ?

Comment: @mah454 I'm not comparing the size of string with MAX_VAL. MAX_VAL has 10 digits and MIN_VAL has size 11 including '-'

Comment: The above solution won't handle numbers of the same length but that are numerically larger in magnitude than `Integer.MAX/MIN_VAL`. You could do it by checking the length, then lexicographically comparing the string to the string representation of max/min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
String str = "987654987855";
String max = String.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
String min = String.valueOf(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
BigInteger b1 =    new BigInteger(str);
BigInteger b_max = new BigInteger(max);
BigInteger b_min = new BigInteger(min);
boolean isOutOfRange = b1.compareTo(b_max) > 0 || b1.compareTo(b_min) < 0;
System.out.println(isOutOfRange); // Output true
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/iJNMGT)

Comment: Thank you! It seems a bit complicated but it gets the work done.

Comment: `BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` is a sufficient and more concise way to construct `b_max`. Note that the min/max values can be preconstructed and stored in static final fields, so you don't have to construct each time.

Answer (score 1):

Parse it as a long first, then check if its in range of the integer max and min.

```
long value = Long.parseLong(inputString);
if (value < Integer.MAX_VALUE && value > Integer.MIN_VALUE) 
     doWhatYouWantToDo();
```

Comment: This won't work for 20000000000000000. Numbers that are greater than long will have an exception.

Comment: well wtf is greater than a long

Comment: Just add the input until it throws no exceptions

Comment: 2000000000000 is a number that's greater than a Long. When the string contains no numbers, I want it to return 0, which needs NumberFormatException. Therefore, I can't just surround it with try/catch.

Comment: @Joe any number greater than `Long.MAX_VALUE`. I hear there are a few such numbers ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to directly parse the value as int, if it's not within the Integer range, NumberFormatException will be thrown

```
String number = "78654567788";
try {
    Integer.parseInt(number);
    System.out.println("Within the range");
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("out of range");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Speed-wise, your code is probably fine. The bigger problem is that it's not correct, because it's not the case that all strings with length of at least ten represent strings that exceed the range, even assuming they only contain `0-9` and `-`.

To do that correctly, you'd need to compare the string to the string representations of the limits:

```
// Some constants.
static final String MAX_VALUE_STRING = Integer.toString(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
static final String MIN_VALUE_STRING = Integer.toString(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

static int parseClamped(String str) {
  // Assuming str.matches("-?[0-9]+") is true.

  if (str.startsWith("-")) {
    // Negative numbers longer than MIN_VALUE.
    // Obviously less than MIN_VALUE.
    if (str.length() > MIN_VALUE_STRING.length()) {
      return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }

    // Negative numbers of the same length as MIN_VALUE.
    // Less than MIN_VALUE if it is lexicographically greater.
    if (str.length() == MIN_VALUE_STRING.length() && str.compareTo(MIN_VALUE_STRING) > 0) {
      return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
  } else {
    // Positive numbers longer than MAX_VALUE.
    // Obviously greater than MAX_VALUE.
    if (str.length() > MAX_VALUE_STRING.length()) {
      return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    // Positive numbers of the same length as MIN_VALUE.
    // Greater than MAX_VALUE if it is lexicographically greater.
    if (str.length() == MAX_VALUE_STRING.length() && str.compareTo(MAX_VALUE_STRING) > 0) {
      return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
  }

  return Integer.parseInt(str);
}
```

You could write this more concisely with a helper method:

```
static boolean longerThanOrAfter(String str, String c) {
  return str.length() > c.length() || str.compareTo(c) > 0;
}

static int parseClamped(String str) {
  // Assuming str.matches("-?[0-9]+") is true.

  if (str.startsWith("-")) {
    if (longerThanOrAfter(str, MIN_VALUE_STRING)) {
      return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
  } else {
    if (longerThanOrAfter(str, MAX_VALUE_STRING)) {
      return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
  }
  return Integer.parseInt(str);
}
```

This is efficient because it doesn't allocate any new objects (at least, not outside the `String.compareTo` method).

But that's at the expense of lacking validation of the string. If you can't guarantee your input is numeric, you can check with a precompiled regex. That won't be terrible performance-wise, but more work is still slower than no work.

And, of course, `Integer.parseInt` allows positive values to start with a `+`, so you may want to consider handling that. This can be done in the same pattern, by comparing against a constant whose value is `"+" + MAX_VALUE_STRING`.